# Akka FSM "timeout" over a measure that is not time (in Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, state-machine

I was trying to use the FSM in Akka to model the states of a protocol (handshake, transmission, payload decoding...). I want to define something akin to a timeout, but in terms of "processed bytes" (e.g. if I'm left in the same state after processing `n` bytes, get out of here). Simply put, I would like to redefine the behavior of `stateTimeout` property. Any  ideas on how to idiomatically achieve this?

Comment: Do bytes come in as an actor message, so you can count them and decide to switch state?

Comment: No :-\ It's part of the actor's state to know how many bytes it has consumed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a certain state `X` and a method `def isDone(x: D): Boolean` which determines that “time’s up”, you can do something like this:

```
when(X) (({
  case Event(...) => ...
  ...
}: StateFunction) andThen {
  case State(_, data, _, _, _) if isDone(data) => // return new state
  case x => x
})
```

Unfortunately the type ascription is necessary, and andThen takes a full Function1, making it a bit more verbose than I’d like. I see that this is useful, will think about how to make it easier.